# Reading Go gctrace output

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I have gctrace output that looks like this:

```
gc 6 @48.155s 15%: 0.093+12360+0.32 ms clock, 0.18+7720/21356/3615+0.65 ms cpu, 11039->13278->6876 MB, 14183 MB goal, 8 P
```

I am not sure how to read the CPU times in particular. I understand that it is broken down into three phases (STW sweep termination, concurrent mark/scan, and STW mark termination), but I'm not sure what the + signs mean (i.e. `0.18+7720` and `3615+0.65`). What do these + signs signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, they look like assist and termination times;

```
// CPU time
0.18    : **STW** Sweep termination.
7720ms  : Mark/Scan - Assist Time (GC performed in line with allocation).
21356ms : Mark/Scan - Background GC time.
3615ms  : Mark/Scan - Idle GC time.
0.65ms  : **STW** Mark termination.
```

I think it changes (or it may) over various Go versions and you can find more detailed info at [runtime package docs](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/).

```
Currently, it is:
    gc # @#s #%: #+#+# ms clock, #+#/#/#+# ms cpu, #->#-># MB, # MB goal, # P
where the fields are as follows:
    gc #        the GC number, incremented at each GC
    @#s         time in seconds since program start
    #%          percentage of time spent in GC since program start
    #+...+#     wall-clock/CPU times for the phases of the GC
    #->#-># MB  heap size at GC start, at GC end, and live heap
    # MB goal   goal heap size
    # P         number of processors used
```

Example [here](https://github.com/ardanlabs/gotraining/tree/master/topics/profiling/godebug/gctrace#running-a-godebug-gc-trace)

See also [Interpreting GC trace output](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/J-Lh4WQgd6I)

```
gc 6 @48.155s 15%: 0.093+12360+0.32 ms clock,
0.18+7720/21356/3615+0.65 ms cpu, 11039->13278->6876 MB, 14183 MB goal, 8 P
```

- **gc 6**
- **@48.155s** since program start
- **15%:** of time spent in GC since program start
- **0.093+12360+0.32 ms clock** stop-the-world (STW) sweep termination + concurrent
  mark and scan + and STW mark termination
- **0.18+7720/21356/3615+0.65 ms cpu** (GC performed in
  line with allocation), background GC time, and idle GC time
- **11039->13278->6876 MB** heap size at GC start, at GC end, and live heap
- **8 P** number of processors used

Comment: A bit confused with heap size at GC start, at GC end, and live heap numbers. There was 11039MB heap size, including garbage, before the GC start, and how it is possible to have 13278MB heap size after the GC end ? I suppose that heap size at GC doest not include garbage size. Because of GC phase remove the garbage from heap, it must be decreased. The next number - live heap, how did we get 6876 MB of live heap ? Live heap is a heap size w/o garbage ?